# Woocommerce - Add custom email footer to specific email template

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have setup a new class which extends `WC_Email` to notify users when a new product has been published.

I am trying to add some text into the footer of this email without effecting the other email templates. I notice within the `WC_Email` class, the following is being called in the _constructer to add text into the footer text.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_footer_text', array( $this, 'email_footer_replace_site_title' ) );

public
function email_footer_replace_site_title($string)
    {
        return str_replace( '{site_title}', $this->get_blogname(), $string );
    }
```

I have copied this into my custom class which extends WC_Email like the below but for some reason it's not outputting.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_footer_text', array( $this, 'email_footer_replace_site_title' ) );

public
function email_footer_replace_site_title($string)
    {
        $string .= $string . 'Test';
        return str_replace( '{site_title}', $this->get_blogname(), $string );
    }
```

I'm conscious you can hook into the `woocommerce_email_footer` action but this outputs before the actual footer text.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Are you sure the function is actually being called? Try `echo 'testtt';` in your function and check the echo's output.

Comment: Hi Sally, no it's not outputting anything...

Comment: How do you instantiate your class; from which hook? Can you show the code?